# Adding custom tags to AWS data catalog assets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm new to AWS, and working on setting up a glue data catalog.

One of our needs is to assign some custom tags to each table in our data catalog. For example, each table needs tags such as 'owner', 'curator' and 'link for more details'.

It doesn't seem that AWS data catalog supports this function - how do you get around doing this?

Thx in advance!